# How to load data from redux store when redirecting to a new page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-router

I have two pages; the first one called `QuizHomePage` and which contains a welcome message and a button which allows to user to start a quiz.

QuizHomePage.tsx:

```
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import { questionRequest, startQuiz } from "../../actions/index";
import AppBar from "../../components/common/AppBar";
import history from "../../history/history";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        root: {
            textAlign: "center",
            margin: theme.spacing(10)
        },
        button: {
            marginTop: theme.spacing(6)
        }

    }));

interface IProps {
    questionRequest: () => void;
    startQuiz: () => void;
}

const QuizHomePage = (props: IProps) => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const { questionRequest, startQuiz } = props;

    const handleStartQuiz = () => {
        questionRequest();
        startQuiz();
        return history.push("/contentQuiz");
    };
    return (<>
        <AppBar />
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Typography
                color="textPrimary"
                gutterBottom
                variant="h2">
                Test your javascript skills
            </Typography>
            <Typography
                color="textSecondary"
                gutterBottom
                variant="h6">
                Please click the start button to launch the Quiz
        </Typography>
            <Button
                className={classes.button}
                color="secondary"
                onClick={handleStartQuiz}
                variant="contained">Start</Button>
        </div>
    </>);
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    return {
        startQuiz: () => dispatch(startQuiz()),
        questionRequest: () => dispatch<any>(questionRequest())
    };
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(QuizHomePage);
```

When I click the `Start` button I dispatch 2 actions `questionRequest` which executes a promise and return the list of all questions from the database and `startQuiz` which dispatch an action to update the state of the quiz, then the user will be redirected to the quiz question page which described by this code:

```
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import SyntaxHighlighter from "react-syntax-highlighter";
import { dark } from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism";
import { incrementQuestion, IQuestion } from "../../actions/index";
import ContentQuiz from "../../components/ContentQuiz";

interface IProps {
  currentQuestionNumber: number;
  questions: IQuestion[];
}

const QuizzContainer = (props: IProps) => {
  const { currentQuestionNumber, questions } = props;

  const currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionNumber];
  const handleNextQuiz = () => {
    incrementQuestion();
  };

  return (
    <ContentQuiz
      questionNumber={currentQuestionNumber}
      handleClick={handleNextQuiz}>
      <div>
        <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom> What's the output of </Typography>
        <>
          <SyntaxHighlighter language="javascript" style={dark}>
            {currentQuestion.questionDescription}
          </SyntaxHighlighter>
        </>

      </div>
    </ContentQuiz>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
  const { currentQuestionNumber, questions } = state.quiz;

  return {
    currentQuestionNumber,
    questions
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { incrementQuestion })(QuizzContainer);
```

actions.ts:

```
export const questionRequest = (): ThunkAction<void, AppState, null, Action<string>> => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch(startQuestionRequest());
    getQuestionsApi().then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
      const { data } = response;
      dispatch(questionSuccess(data.result));
    },
      (error: AxiosError) => {
        let errorMessage = "Internal Server Error";
        if (error.response) {
          errorMessage = error.response.data.error;
        }
        dispatch(questionFail(errorMessage));
        dispatch(errorAlert(errorMessage));
      });
  };
};
```

I got an error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'questionDescription' of undefined
```

it's normally because for react the `questions`variable is undefined. I realized that the questions array is not updated quickly but after some amount of time due to the server response that's why the QuizzContainer`returns the error mentioned below when it tries to mount the component.
Is it a good approach to lazy load the component in order to wait the fetching of questions from server and then mounting the` QuizContainer `component? I tried`useEffect`which normally behaves as`componentDidMount` but it does not work with my issue.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my question using this update:

```
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import SyntaxHighlighter from "react-syntax-highlighter";
import { dark } from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism";
import { incrementQuestion, IQuestion } from "../../actions/index";
import ContentQuiz from "../../components/ContentQuiz";

interface IProps {
  currentQuestionNumber: number;
  loadingData: boolean;
  questions: IQuestion[];
  questionRequest: () => void;
}

const QuizzContainer = (props: IProps) => {
  const { currentQuestionNumber, loadingData, questions, questionRequest } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    questionRequest();
  });

  const currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionNumber];
  const handleNextQuiz = () => {
    incrementQuestion();
  };

  return (
    <div>
   {loadingData ? ("Loading ...") : (
    <ContentQuiz
      questionNumber={currentQuestionNumber}
      handleClick={handleNextQuiz}>
      <div>
        <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom> What's the output of </Typography>
        <>
          <SyntaxHighlighter language="javascript" style={dark}>
            {currentQuestion.questionDescription}
          </SyntaxHighlighter>
        </>

      </div>
    </ContentQuiz>
)}
</div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
  const { currentQuestionNumber, loadingData, questions } = state.quiz;

  return {
    currentQuestionNumber,
    loadingData,
    questions
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  return {
    incrementQuestion: () => dispatch(incrementQuestion()),
    questionRequest: () => dispatch<any>(questionRequest())
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(QuizzContainer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use async and await here. If you don't wait until the promise gets resolved and navigate the user to the next page, you can never guarantee that the user will see the question as soon as page loads.

```
 const handleStartQuiz = async () => {
        awit questionRequest();
        await startQuiz();
        return history.push("/contentQuiz");
    }
```

**Second approach: (I don't recommend)**
Don't render the question unless you have questions filled in the redux state.

```
return(
     { questions &&  <ContentQuiz> ... </ContentQuiz> }
)
```